# Spring Data Geode Region has local scope and cannot listen to remote Region events

Tags: geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

I am using Spring Data for Apache Geode for a Spring Boot app that uses a remote Apache Geode server. To set up local Regions I am using `@Configuration` class like:

```
@Configuration
public class GeodeConfig {

  public static Region<String, String> myRegion;

  @Bean("setupMyRegion")
  public Region<String, String> setupMyRegion(GemFireCache cache) {

    Region<String, String> r = cache.getRegion("myRegion");
    myRegion = r;

    return r;
  }
}
```

This enables me to put and get data with the Region.

When I register interest in subscribing to a key, the subscription is setup with scope=LOCAL like this:

```
org.apach.geode.inter.cache.LocalRegion 4439 logKeys: org.apache.geode.internal.cache.LocalRegion[path='/myRegion';scope=LOCAL';dataPolicy=NORMAL; concurrencyChecksEnabled] refreshEntriesFromServerKeys count=1 policy=KEYS_VALUES
```

and I guess that I want to set it up as a `CACHING_PROXY` so that later, on subscribing to events in the Region, the local subscription will see the server Region events.

I've set `subscriptionEnabled=TRUE` for the `@ClientCacheApplication` and I am trying to set

```
clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY
```

I don't know where to do this. I've tried the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` annotation but the Region is still being set to local.

If I try to create a Region Factory from the `GemFireCache` it gives me an error that the method `createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut)` is "undefined" for the type `GemFireCache`.

THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it is bad practice to use the Apache Geode API directly to configure beans in a *Spring* context.  For example...

```java
  @Bean("MyRegion")
  public Region<String, Object> myRegion(GemFireCache cache) {
    return cache.getRegion("myRegion");
  }
```

Or using:

```java
  @Bean("MyRegion")
  public Region<String, Object> myRegion(ClientCache clientCache) {
    return clientCache.createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
      .create("MyRegion");
  }
```

Both approaches above are **not** recommended!

*Spring Data for Apache Geode* (SDG) contains specific *Spring* [`FactoryBeans`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) to do the same thing.  For instance, the SDG [`ClientRegionFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/ClientRegionFactoryBean.html).

You would use the `ClientRegionFactoryBean` in your *Spring* application configuration as follows:

```java
@Bean("MyRegion")
ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, Object> myRegion(ClientCache clientCache) {

  ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, Object> myRegion = 
    new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();

  myRegion.setCache(clientCache);
  myRegion.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY);

  return myRegion;
}
```

There are SDG `FactoryBeans` for different types of Geode objects, such a [client] `Regions`, `Indexes`, `DiskStores`, `GatewayReceivers`, `GatewaySenders`, etc.

These `FactoryBeans` are essential in ensuring the the "lifecycle" of the Geode objects (e.g. `Region(s)`) are properly synced to the lifecycle of the *Spring* container. By forgoing the use of SDG's `FactoryBeans` you are effectively ignoring the lifecycle coordination provided by the *Spring* container and custom (framework) `FactoryBeans`, and are therefore responsible for the lifecycle of the Geode objects themselves when using Geode's API direct in *Spring* config.  This is one of the primary reasons SDG's exists in the first place.

A "client" `Region` must be a `*PROXY` (e.g. `PROXY` or `CACHING_PROXY`) in order to enable subscriptions and receive interesting events from servers for that Region.  This is because the Geode cluster (servers) maintain a subscription queue for clients when they connect, which contain events that the client has expressed interests in receiving.

For `*PROXY` client `Regions`, this also means that the client `Region` must have a corresponding server-side, peer cache `Region` by the same name.

You can simplify Region creation in general, and client Region creation in particular, by using SDG's Annotation-based configuration model, and specifically, `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions` or `@EnableCachingDefinedRegions`.

For instance:

```java
@ClientCacheApplication(subscriptionsEnabled = true)
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = SomeEntity.class, 
  clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
class GeodeConfiguration {
  ...
}
```

Of course, this assumes you have defined application domain model entity classes, such as:

```java
package example.app.model;

import ...;

@Region("MyRegion")
class SomeEntity {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  ...
}
```

The `ClientRegionFactoryBean` would be typed accordingly: `ClientRegionFactoryBean<Long, SomeEntity>`.

See the SDG Annotation-based configuration model [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config) for more details, and specifically [Annotation configuration covering Region definitions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-regions).

The [`@EnableClusterDefinedRegions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableClusterDefinedRegions.html) annotation defines client-side `Regions` for all existing server-side (cluster) `Regions` to which the client connects.

For example, if you start a cluster in *Gfsh* as follows:

```
gfsh>start locator --name=MyLocator ...

gfsh>start server --name=MyServer ...

gfsh>create region --name=Example --type=PARTITION

gfsh>create region --name=AnotherExample --type=REPLICATE
```

And then connect a *Spring Boot*, Apache Geode `ClientCache` application to this cluster by using the following Geode configuration:

```java
@ClientCacheApplication
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions(clientRegionShortcut = 
  ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
class GeodeConfiguration {
  ...
}
```

Then the *Spring Boot*, Apache Geode `ClientCache` application would have 2 *Spring* configured client Region beans with names "Example" and "AnotherExample" both of type, `CACHING_PROXY`.

If there are NO server-side Regions presently in the cluster, then the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` would not define any client-side Regions.

Anyway, I hope this makes sense and helps!

Cheers!

Comment: thanks John, in the last example using @EnableClusterDefinedRegions, what additional variable setup do you need in the spring boot client to put, get to the AnotherExample region.... and register for interesting events from that region... without the client throwing a compile time error: what is this unknown region variable? In other words do you still have to declare a ClientRegionRegionFactoryBean for AnotherExample to use it on the spring boot client?

Comment: When using the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` annotation, you do not need to explicitly declare beans in the *Spring* context of type `ClientRegionFactoryBean` for all server-side Regions, in order to have a corresponding client-side [*PROXY] Region by the same name.  That is the convenience provided by the annotation.  You could then inject the client Region bean into any application component managed by *Spring* using the standard autowiring, `@Resource(name = "Example") private Region<Object, Object> example`.  Continued...

Comment: The same applies for "AnotherExample" Region and any other server-side Region.  When using SBDG, SBDG also provides a `GemfireTemplate` bean for each (client) Region defined.  See SBDG's `GemfireTemplate` support (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.3.x/reference/html5/#geode-data-access-region-templates).  See here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:template) and here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html) for more details about the SDG `GemfireTemplate` class.

Comment: Regarding... *what additional variable setup do you need in the spring boot client to put, get to the AnotherExample region* ... You simply need to inject either the Region bean or the GemfireTemplate for the Region to perform data access operations on that Region (e.g. "AnotherExample").

Comment: To "register interests", if you have a reference to the Region (as in injected bean), then you could use Geode's Region API to register interests (e.g. https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#registerInterest-K-boolean-boolean-).  Alternatively, and recommended, you could declare a `RegionConfigurer` bean (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/RegionConfigurer.html), filter by beanName (e.g. "AnotherExample") and then register interests using the `ClientRegionFactoryBean` API...

Comment: Using: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/ClientRegionFactoryBean.html#setInterests-org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.Interest:A-

Comment: Regarding... *do you still have to declare a ClientRegionFactoryBean for AnotherExample to use it on the spring boot client?*  NO.  See SDG's test suite for a an example of using the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` annotation (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/master/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableClusterDefinedRegionsIntegrationTests.java).  This test is not registering interests on any client Region auto-configured by the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` ...

Comment: ... , but it would be a simple matter to do so using the `RegionConfigurer` as I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi John, I try the @Resource injection in a worker class and get null pointer. It’s not init’d... aargh.. also if using the *not* recommended clientCache.create approach at the top, I can put and get to client and server region, but if I try and register interest in a key and put a key into the server region the spring boot client region isn’t seeing the event.... I’m gonna try and get a region factory going but if you have any comment, it’s appreciated.

Comment: client is a spring boot geode client and server is gfsh standard Geode server on a remote box.....

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here was that the class in which I wanted to use the Geode regions was not registering in the Spring container because I was using `new` to use that class instead of using `@Autowired` annotation for Spring. That meant that when I setup the Geode regions per @JohnBlum's answer using `@Resource(name = "Example") private Region<Object, Object> example` the autowiring was still producing null objects.

Also the class where I wanted to use the regions was in another package outside of my `@ComponentScan` so I had to amend the `@ComponentScan` to find that package.

Thing is, once I got through these configurations and properly setup the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` (real easy once you know how!!) and I can put and get with the regions, the [register interests doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226331).

The problem with the `register interests` was that my `application.properties` had

`spring.data.gemfire.cache.client.durable-client-id=myListener`

and when I removed that property the `CacheListenerAdapter` started to receive events from the server!