# Spring Data Geode register interest is not receiving events

Tags: geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188513) I've setup a Spring Data Geode Client application with

`@EnableClusterDefinedRegions(clientRegionShortcut=ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)`

and by ensuring all classes are autowired then using the `@Resource` the Geode server regions are setup and instantiated on the client.

```
@Resource(name = "request")
private Region<String, Request> request;
```

I can put and get on the regions like this. However when I try and register interest in a key on the server the updates from other clients to the server are received by the spring boot client. The register interest code:

```
request.registerInterestForAllKeys();
request.getAttributesMutator().addCacheListener(new myListener());
```

The logs show the interest is added to the region:

```
DEBUG [main] org.apach.geode.inter.cache.GemFireCacheImpl 4388 registerInterestStarted: registerInterestsStarted: new count = 1
TRACE [main] org.apach.geode.inter.InternalDataSerializer 2194 basicWriteObject: basicWriteObject: KEYS_VALUES
TRACE [main] org.apach.geode.inter.InternalDataSerializer 1535 writeDSFID: writeDSFID 37 class=class org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.InterestResultPolicyImpl
TRACE [main] org.apach.geode.cache.clien.inter.OpExecutorImpl 568 executeOnQueuesAndReturnPrimaryResult: sending org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.RegisterInterestOp$RegisterInterestOpImpl@5e1a7d3 to backups: []
TRACE [main] org.apach.geode.cache.clien.inter.OpExecutorImpl 584 executeOnQueuesAndReturnPrimaryResult: sending org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.RegisterInterestOp$RegisterInterestOpImpl@5e1a7d3 to primary: Connection[1.2.3.4:40404]@613231852
TRACE [main] org.apach.geode.cache.clien.inter.AbstractOp 85 attemptSend: Sending op=RegisterInterestOp$RegisterInterestOpImpl using Connection[1.2.3.4:40404]@613231852
```

When another client adds or changes a value on the server region that event is not getting to the spring boot client. The CacheListenerAdapter with usual `afterCreate` and `afterUpdate` overrides is not called.

The use case is to register and unregister to lots of different keys on the fly.

If I use the spring boot app itself to put to the local region, then the event handler *is* being called. So it's not an issue with the spring boot code this is a connection pool & server registration issue of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my `application.properties` had

`spring.data.gemfire.cache.client.durable-client-id=myListener`

For some reason a durable client cannot run a `CacheListenerAdapter`