# spring data geode pool is not resolvable as a Pool in the application context

Tags: spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

I've come back to a `@SpringBootApplication` project that uses `spring-geode-starter` with version `1.2.4` although the same error happens with upgrades to `1.5.6` version.

It sets up a Geode client using

```
@Component
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions(clientRegionShortcut=ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY)
```

and in order to register interest subscriptions over HTTP, also

```
@Configuration
@EnableGemFireHttpSession
```

with a bean

```
@Bean
public ReactiveSessionRepository<?> reactiveSessionRepository() {
    return new ReactiveMapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
}
```

On starting the application the spring data geode client connects to the server (Geode version `1.14`) and auto copies `regions` back to the client, which is great.

However, after all the region handles are copied over, there's an error with the `@EnableGemFireHttpSession` which is

`Error creating bean with name 'ClusteredSpringSessions' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/config/annotation/web/http/GemFireHttpSessionConfiguration.class]` and `[gemfirePool] is not resolvable as a Pool in the application context`

The first info message in the logs is:

```
org.springframework.session.data.gemfire.config.annotation.web.http.GemFireHttpSessionConfiguration 1109 sessionRegionAttributes: Expiration is not allowed on Regions with a data management policy of PROXY
org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.AbstractFactoryBeanSupport 277 lambda$logInfo$3: Falling back to creating Region [ClusteredSpringSessions] in Cache [Web]
```

So the client is trying to create a region `ClusteredSpringSessions` but it can't. The problem appears to resolve itself if I define a connection pool for HTTP, with a pool connection `bean` like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableGemFireHttpSession(poolName="devPool")
public class SessionConfig {

@Bean
public ReactiveSessionRepository<?> reactiveSessionRepository() {
    return new ReactiveMapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
}

@Bean("devPool")
PoolFactoryBean sessionPool() {
    PoolFactoryBean pool = new PoolFactoryBean();
    ConnectionEndpoint ce = new ConnectionEndpoint("1.2.3.4", 10334);       
    pool.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
    pool.addLocators(ce);
    return pool;
}
```

}

There is still the `Expiration is not allowed on Regions with a data management policy of PROXY` info message in the log, but this time the `Falling back to creating Region [ClusteredSpringSessions] in Cache [Web]` appears to work.

I don't understand why a default pool can't connect.

If a pool is defined then in version `1.2.4` that can cause [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226331/spring-data-geode-register-interest-is-not-receiving-events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** (SBDG), which is an excellent choice (thank you), then you can simply include the `spring-geode-starter-session` dependency on your `@SpringBootApplication` classpath, which removes the need to explicitly annotate your *Spring Boot* application with SSDG's `@EnableGemFireHttpSession` annotation.

> See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-session-configuration) for more details. I also have a Sample application demonstrating the use of SSDG, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/guides/caching-http-session.html). The [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/guides/caching-http-session.html) and [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/tree/1.5.6/spring-geode-samples/caching/http-session) for this example, along with other examples, can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-samples)).

Also, I would generally advise that users drive the GemFire/Geode cluster configuration from the application and not let the cluster dictate the `Regions` (and/or other components/configuration) that the client gets. However, SDG's `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` annotation is provided and generally useful in the case you do not have control over the GemFire/Geode cluster your application is using. Still, in the (HTTP) Session UC, the GemFire/Geode cluster would need a *Session* `Region` (which defaults to "*ClusteredSpringSessions*" as [determined](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.6.0/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/config/annotation/web/http/EnableGemFireHttpSession.java#L198-L210) by *Spring Session for Apache Geode* (SSDG) itself) anyway.

OK, now to the problem at hand...

I think what is happening here is, due to backwards compatibility and legacy reasons, *Spring Data for Apache Geode* (SDG), on which both SSDG and SBDG are based; SBDG additionally pulls in SSDG as well, defined a GemFire/Geode `Pool` by the name of "gemfirePool", specifically when using the SDG XML space and using/defining a [DataSource configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#data-access:datasource).

So, it is somewhat naively assumed users would be explicitly defining a `Pool` and calling it "gemfirePool", and not simply relying on a "default" `Pool` connection to the GemFire/Geode cache server (namely "localhost", `40404`, or if using Locators (recommended), "localhost" and `10334`).

However, for development purposes, and in SBDG specifically, I rely on the fact that GemFire/Geode creates a "DEFAULT" `Pool` anyway (when no explicit `Pool` is defined), and forgo the strict requirement that a "gemfirePool" should exist. But, SBDG builds on SSDG and SDG and they still rely on the legacy arrangement (for [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.6.0/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/config/annotation/web/http/EnableGemFireHttpSession.java#L181-L196)).

I have filed an [Issue ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/issues/37) in SSDG to change this and better align SSDG with what SBDG prefers going forward, but I simply have not gotten around to it yet. My apologies for your inconvenience.

Anyway, it is a simple change you can make externally from your *Spring Boot* application, in `application.properties` like so (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.5.6/spring-geode-samples/caching/http-session/src/main/resources/application.properties#L5) from the HTTP Session Sample I referenced from SBDG above). This will allow you to configure the *Session* `Region` `Pool` "name".

> Also note, it is possible to change the name of the *Session* `Region` used by the client if what comes down from the cluster when you are using SDG's `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` and the `Region` definition pulled down from the cluster is named differently on the server-side using this [property](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.5.6/spring-geode-samples/caching/http-session/src/main/resources/application.properties#L6).

Additionally, you can also configure the client *Session* `Region` data policy using properties as well (for [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.6.0/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/config/annotation/web/http/EnableGemFireHttpSession.java#L118-L119)).

Regarding the Expiration "info" message you are seeing in the logs...

Since the client *Session* `Region` is a `PROXY` by default, then Expiration, Eviction and other `Region` data management policies (e.g. Compression, etc), do not actually make much sense.

In fact, SSDG is smart about whether to apply additional `Region` data management policies locally or not (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.6.0/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/config/annotation/web/http/GemFireHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L1097-L1111), and specifically, [this logic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.6.0/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/config/annotation/web/http/GemFireHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L1116-L1132)).

The message you are seeing in your application logs is in fact [coming from SSDG](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.6.0/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/config/annotation/web/http/GemFireHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L1109-L1110), specifically. This message really serves as a reminder that your Session state management is actually "managed" on the server-side (when the application client is using a `PROXY` or even a `CACHING_PROXY` `Region` for that matter) and that the corresponding server-side, or cluster *Sessions* `Region` should be configured manually and appropriately, with Expiration policies as well as other things if necessary. Otherwise, no Session expiration would actually happen!

I hope all this makes since.

If you continue to have problems, feel free to file an Issue ticket and provide an example test or small application replicating your problem.

Comment: I should also make you aware that SBDG `1.2.x` is already EOL. See the SBDG project page (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode#learn) for more details.