# Spring Boot for GemFire - Error creating bean with name 'continuousQueryListenerContainer'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am using spring boot 2.5.6 and integrating gemfire with it.

Getting exception while deploying the application on PCF as:

**Error creating bean with name 'continuousQueryListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/ContinuousQueryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Pool with name [DEFAULT] was found**

dependency which I am using to support gemfire is:

```
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-gemfire-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** [and optionally, VMware Tanzu (Pivotal) GemFire] (SBDG) `1.2.x` is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.x/gradle.properties#L9) *Spring Boot* `2.2.x`, not `2.5.x`! Therefore, this combination is not recommended.

It is SBDG `1.5.6` that is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.5.6/gradle.properties#L11) *Spring Boot* `2.5.6`, and the latest version in the *Spring Boot* `2.5.x` / SBDG `1.5.x` release series is currently, [`1.5.7`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.5.7/gradle.properties#L20) (with *Spring Boot* [`2.5.7`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.5.7/gradle.properties#L11)).

Additionally, you should also prefer to be on the latest maintenance/patch release (e.g. [`1.2.13.RELEASE`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.13.RELEASE/gradle.properties#L18); the last patch release in the `1.2` release series) for any *major.minor* version (e.g. `1.2`).

Presumably, you are still on SBDG `1.2`, even though it is [**now EOL**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode#learn), because you have a GemFire `9.8` cluster (?), on which SBDG `1.2` [is based](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.x/gradle.properties#L7). Or, in your case, presumably the version of the PCC cluster in PCF is based on GemFire `9.8`??

Finally, you can review all of this information in the SBDG Wiki, [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-VMware-Tanzu-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix#version-compatibility-matrix).

As an aside, this problem is not unlike the problem @rupweb had in this question, ["*spring data geode pool is not resolvable as a Pool in the application context*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70025183/spring-data-geode-pool-is-not-resolvable-as-a-pool-in-the-application-context).

However, this problem is also fundamentally different inside a PCC context, particularly when using SBDG. SBDG derives the PCC cluster (Locators/Servers) connection metadata for the client (the SBDG app) from the PCC environment, namely from VCAP application & service environment variables. It then proceeds in [configuring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/ClientSecurityAutoConfiguration.java#L202-L207) the *Locators* of all Pools defined. The [SDG property](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/ClientSecurityAutoConfiguration.java#L113) generally refers to all Pools created, which is simply the "DEFAULT" Pool when setting up the `ClientCache` to begin with.  Of course, the property can be specialized for specific "named" Pools (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-properties)), however, this is not usually necessary.

Anyway, you can go on to [see](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.2.0.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/ClientCacheConfiguration.java#L127-L148) in ***Spring Data for Apache Geode*** [and optionally, VMware Tanzu GemFire] (SDG) specifically, in the `2.2.0.RELEASE`, on which SBDG `1.2.0.RELEASE` [is based](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/gradle.properties#L10-L11), that the "DEFAULT" Pool is initialized from the `spring.data.gemfire.pool.locators` property setup by SBDG when the app is deployed to PCF, connecting to a PCC cluster.

It is GemFire/Geode itself that sets up a "DEFAULT" `Pool` when a `ClientCache` instance is created (which SBDG *auto-configures* by default; see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-clientcache-applications)).

However, this can be disrupted for 2 reasons (possibly others):

1. First, if you explicitly declared the SDG `@ClientCacheApplication` annotation on your `@SpringBootApplication` class, or another Spring `@Configuration` class, then you effectively override the *auto-configuration*. Don't do this when using SBDG. If you need to customize the `ClientCache` configuration, use appropriate properties in `application.properties.`
2. If you explicitly define/declare a `Pool` (bean) yourself, then GemFire/Geode forgoes the creation of a "DEFAULT" `Pool`.

Of course, it is hard to say what is going on for sure since you have not shared any snippets of your application configuration.

I know that the auto-configuration for SDG/GemFire/Geode CQ provided by SBDG works correctly given this [Integration Test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/cq/AutoConfiguredContinuousQueryIntegrationTests.java) in the SBDG test suite.

> NOTE: There is nothing particularly special about the [imported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/cq/AutoConfiguredContinuousQueryIntegrationTests.java#L126) STDG `ClientServerIntegerationTestsConfiguration` class ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/tests/integration/config/ClientServerIntegrationTestsConfiguration.java)) used by the GemFire client test configuration, other than coordinating the `CacheServer` port and client `Pool` port accordingly, given the port is dynamically generated. The client also connects directly to the `CacheServer` in the test, which is of no consequence.

You can also try 1 of 2 things:

1. First, you can explicitly define a `Pool` bean with the name "DEFAULT", like so:

```java
@Configuration
@EnablePool(name = "DEFAULT")
class AdditionalGemFireConfiguration {
  // ...
}
```

By using SDG's `@EnablePool` annotation, named "DEFAULT", it will make sure a `Pool` by the name "DEFAULT" exists. And, because SBDG generically refers to all Pools (using the property `spring.data.gemfire.pool.locators`), then the "DEFAULT" `Pool` should pick up the configuration coming from SBDG, which again, comes from the VCAP environment inside PCF when using PCC.

2. Alternatively, you can configure a `BeanPostProcessor` to customize the SDG `ContinuousQueryListenerContainer` bean *auto-configured* by SBDG, and set the custom `Pool` name, accordingly.

Both of these approaches should not be necessary when using the SBDG project and following the conventions described in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/) (also [see](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#cloudfoundry)).

Let's start with this information, and iterate if necessary.

Comment: Thank You Blum!!

It worked after replacing spring-gemfire-starter 1.2.0.RELEASE with spring-data-gemfire 2.2.0.RELEASE.

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-gemfire</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>